# Call a function in each action of controller in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to call a common function in every action before the action code is executed

**Example**

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{

 public function actionTest(TestFunction1){
      echo "Inside Action To execute"
 }

 private function TestFunction1(){
     echo "Inside Common Function"
 }

}
```

So in this case I'd want the app to first print "Inside Common Function" and after that "Inside Action To execute".

Comment: yii2 has function that runs before action. [beforeAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction()-detail)

Answer (score 1):

you can use beforeAction

it will execute before any function in controller

here is a sample

```
  public function beforeAction($action) {
    $this->abrech_model = new Abrechnung;
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->_session = Yii::$app->session;
    $this->view->params['langfile'] = 'de';
    $this->layout = "template";
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Hello,I know about beforeAction but i want to return an array from that function and also check some stuff in that function how can i do that ?

Comment: 1. You can write code in `beforeAction()` function like you write in any other controller function, so you can check some stuff and return an array.                2. Second approach is you can create a `BaseController` extend with controller and write your desired function in it and than extend all you controller with `BaseController` and you can find that method in all of your controllers which you extend from baseController.

Comment: create your function, and do what you want to do, and then call it in before ,  $this->myfunc or how ever it is

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeAction() function and for return an array you need to declair a public array variable on top and assign the value in this array inside beforeAction() function . Now you can use this public array variable to any action.
Here i am writing your controller code :

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;



class SiteController extends Controller
{


    public $arrData=[];


    public function actionIndex()
    {
      print_r($arrData); // use array here
      return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
      $arrData=[0,1,2,3]; // do here your stuffs 
      return $arrData;
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
public function beforeAction($action){
$this->TestFunction1();
return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Write that function code in main.php file and execute that function for each action

Comment: do you have any working example code that you can share?

Comment: do you have any working example code that you can share?